# Not removing a component from View Why?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I am using below code to remove a code and reload it from scratch but JSF not able to remove the component from tree and after clicking button which is calling below method showing same.

```
 public String collapseTreeById(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
     String treeId = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("treeId");
     UITree tree = (UITree)event.getComponent().findComponent(treeId);
     tree.getParent().getChildren().clear();

     return null;
 }
```

But I am able to view the same components with data in JSF page . What can be issue can any one help me?  It showing page in same state after button press where it was before pressing that button.

Comment: Why do you need to remove components from the view?

Comment: Actually its a big story I have a Richfaces tree i want to reload it to get new data from DB and i am able to reload but issue is that If Suppose i have expand that tree and reload again icon(+/-) gone now i am not able to do anything with that tree..I am not able to fix the issue so i want to recreate that component so somehow issue will fix and tree load without any issue?

Answer (score 0):

I am not a JSF expert and your idea sounds a little bit strange, but maybe try a component binding in the backing bean for the tree?

Comment: That i already done but i am getting issue thats y trying this to recreate whole tree